# How to create new Control type for Product variant attributes

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, e-commerce, nopcommerce

I am beginner in nopCommerce 2.65. I try to create a new Control type for Product variant

attribute. I create a fake product in my nopCommerce test  environment.then add the

product variant attribute **Date picker** to the product.how to create jQuery Datepicker

calander control type for the  **Date picker**.

Is it possible ?

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. Types of control are defined in Nop.Core

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. But I want to use a jQuery Date Calander 

with nopCommerce TextBox. Is it possible? I am clueless 

Please Help me.